# Dreaded OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError on Rubygems when using HTTPS source

Tags: rubygems, openssl

```
$ bundle 
The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.
```

OK, changing the Gemfile to:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

But then:

```
$ bundle 
    Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
    troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/Users/ale/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:917:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

How do I fix this endless SSL mess?

Comment: Thanks but I tried the various `rvm install 2.0.0 --with-openssl-dir=\`brew --prefix openssl\`` and company, but I'm still getting that. It's a nightmare. It's a big nightmare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is explained in detail here: https://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

Comment: Thanks, but I already read that and it didn't fix my problem. Just the workarounds are working, but they're not really a solution, are they?

Comment: The only thing I didn't try was in the comments and for Mountain Lion here, it's the real solution! After installing the `curl-ca-bundle` certificate package with brew do `export SSL_CERT_FILE=/usr/local/opt/curl-ca-bundle/share/ca-bundle.crt` and it will work. You can put that in your .bash_profile then.