# How to tell gem command not to use SSL

Tags: ruby, ssl, rubygems

I am trying to run the `gem` command to install/update some gems, but due to some network restrictions in this area, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    SSL_connect returned=6 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A
```

(I think) this is mainly because of tampering with the SSL certificates.
Is there anyway to tell `gem` not to use `SSL`, to avoid the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dreaded OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError on Rubygems when using HTTPS source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094404/dreaded-opensslsslsslerror-on-rubygems-when-using-https-source)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use HTTP instead of HTTPS if you are unable to solve the certs issue:

```
$ gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org
```

To avoid repeating this every time, either edit your `~/.gemrc` or edit the file through the command line, like this:

```
$ gem sources --add http://rubygems.org
$ gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org
$ gem sources --list

*** CURRENT SOURCES ***
http://rubygems.org
```

Also, en every `Gemfile` you will need to change the first line from:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

To:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Of course it would be much better if you manage to solve the `certs` issue as @p11y suggested on his comment.

Comment: Note: If you get the error `source https://rubygems.org not present in cache` you need to add a forward-slash to the end of the url so you use: `$ gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org/`

Comment: Might also run into this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983442/cant-add-sources-with-gem

Answer (score 29):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. The following, however, did.

Edit .gemrc file

- On Windows c:\Users\yourusername\.gemrc

> Specifically %HOMEPATH% in the event your path is different.
>
> - Thanks goes out to @[AaronChristiansen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2626000/aaron-christiansen) for pointing this out.

add:

```
:ssl_verify_mode: 0
```

It displayed the SSL errors but the install was successful.

Comment: This worked for me when the accepted answer didn't, thanks :) 
In case this doesn't work for anybody, it's worth knowing that `.gemrc` needs to go in specifically `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`, which might not always be your `C:\Users\username` folder. (It wasn't in my case, which had me stumped for a while!)